# What color model is used for the param.blobcolor ? Is it BRG or HSV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, colors

params.blobColor = 44;
//I am going to find blobs for skin color

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the OpenCV documentation

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d0/d7a/classcv_1_1SimpleBlobDetector.html

It says:

> The class implements a simple algorithm for extracting blobs from an
>   image:
>
> 1. Convert the source image to binary images by applying thresholding with several thresholds from minThreshold (inclusive) to maxThreshold
>      (exclusive) with distance thresholdStep between neighboring
>      thresholds.

...

> This class performs several filtrations of returned blobs. You should
>   set filterBy* to true/false to turn on/off corresponding filtration.
>   Available filtrations:
>
> By color. This filter compares the intensity of a binary image at the
>   center of a blob to **blobColor**. If they differ, the blob is filtered
>   out. Use blobColor = 0 to extract dark blobs and blobColor = 255 to
>   extract light blobs.

blobColor is a byte value, it does not actually represent a color so applying color models doesn't make sense. It's neither HSV nor BRG.

According to this tutorial: https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/

This filter operation was or maybe still is broken.